# Is there a way to create a composition function for decorators in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a complete web app with some components which used multiple decorators (HOC).

I was wondering if there is a way to use multiple decorators with one call.

Something like this:

```
export default compose(
  [
    withFunctionality,
    withProvider
  ]
)(MyComponent)
```

The corresponding code should be:

```
export default withProvider(
  withFunctionality(
    MyComponent
  )
)
```

The following code is what i tried:

```
function compose(hocs) {
  return (Component) => hocs.reduce(
    (component, hoc) => hoc(component),
    Component
  )
}
```

However, when doing like so some of my components doesn't work any more.

What might be wrong here?

Comment: I test the compose function and it works. The problem should be in other part of your code..Are you getting any error?

Comment: No errors.. All work without any error, but i got a rollback on some state (which actually do not use this function) and work fine without this function. Strange...

Comment: Yes the compose function is fine, you don't need to change it

Comment: @lissettdm actually yes i need to change it. It work but it doesn't perfect fit in my context. Some functionalities need fix proposed by @aleksxor bellow or change my function with `lodash.flowRight` (propose by @a_m_dev). Each of them work _perfectly_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the classic definition of `compose` function from the great [`recompose`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recompose) package:

```js
const compose = (...funcs) =>
  funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => a(b(...args)), arg => arg)

export default compose
```

If you use `redux` it has [`compose`](https://redux.js.org/api/compose/) function aswell.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer: i accept yours because it is the minimal solution at my problem. Use `_.flowRight` work too but it need to add lodash as dependencies for only one function.

Comment: I use Redux, but my problem doesn't come with redux usage. But maybe it can always replace it. I'll try it out and come back to you

Comment: Redux just has baked in `compose` function so you don't need to define it yourself or add any other dependency to import it into the project.

Comment: It's at least quite weird to give a suggestion to use a library that is not maintained for 4 years (recompose) to resolve a little problem that can fixed by `flowRight` function from `lodash` (or get function from lodash yourself).

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `flowRight` function from lodash as compose function.

Here is a practical example in my GraphQL project in order to inject my queries/mutations to my component:

```js
import { graphql } from "react-apollo";
import { flowRight as compose } from "lodash";


... some react code 


// export like this
export default compose(
  graphql(myQuery),
  graphql(myMutation)
)(MyComponent);
```

This example has been used in GraphSQL context but I think you get the idea of composing some other stuff with your components.

Also [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flowRight) is how `flowRight` function works in lodash documentation.

Comment: I test it out, and actually it solve my problem. Thank you a lot for this discovery!

Comment: thx a lot, in my case is little simpler

`export default flowRight(WithKeyboardAvoiding)(LoginScreen);`